# is this possible to use Map<String, Function> in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter.
I'm trying to use this sentence

```
  Map<String, Function> map = Map();

  Function fun1 = (() => print("TAG : 1111"));
  map.putIfAbsent("test", fun1);
  map["test"]!.call();
```

But in runtime, I've got the error like this.

```
Dart Unhandled Exception: type '_TypeError'
```

I want to use the map including some function because of not supported reflection
Is there any solution in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `map.putIfAbsent()` to:

```dart
map.putIfAbsent("test", () => fun1);
```

Comment: Adding to the comment, the type of `fun1` should be of `Null Function()` otherwise you get `The return type 'Function' isn't a 'Null Function()', as required by the closure's context.`

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, void Function()> mapName = {
    "some string": () {
        // function code
    },
}
```